# Drupal 7 json ouput error -1 with Java Camunda application

Tags: java, json, drupal-7, camunda

I have made a Drupal module with a single page to display only json data like this :

```
drupal_add_http_header('Status', $code);
drupal_json_output($data);
```

`$Code` can be 200, 204, 401, 404 etc.

When my page is called by Postman it's ok.

When my page is called by Java application it's return -1.

I got the full stack trace and I uploaded it on pastebin : http://pastebin.com/PvCeQuU5

Any idea ?

---

I set my hook_menu like this :

```
$items['mymodule/json'] = array(
    'title'             => t('Page title'),
    'page callback'     => array('mymodule_pagejson'),
    'access callback'   => TRUE,
    'type'              => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output',
  );
return $items;
```

Comment: What you attempt to achieve isn't really clear.
are you making requests from Java to Drupal (that's my guess as you use drupal_json_output)?

By the way:

- I believe that the correct usage of `drupal_add_http_header` would take the $code and the name of the error (like: `drupal_add_http_header('Status', '404 Not Found');` as described here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7.x
- Unless you really want your `mymodule/json` to have a visible menu item, the contstant `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` should probably be changed to `MENU_CALLBACK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the delivery callback with drupal_json_output() returns 4 characters even if it's a 204 status.

But 204 status doesn't allow a Content-Lenght more then 0 (as it's said in the RFC) thus the html data layer of java broke down.

Postman shows that Content-Lenght is more then 0 but allows the query to be executed normally.